# How does one change Fishpig blog description/title?

Tags: magento, fishpig

Where do I need to go to change the /blog/ description? I noticed that Fishpig isn't using WordPress's blog description and that there also isn't a setting for changing this within the Fishpig settings page under Magento admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

The description that is placed directly under the blog title is taken from the Settings > General page of the WordPress Admin.

Comment: Changing the 'Site Title' under Settings > General changes the Title. However, none of these fields change the description

Comment: Do you mean the meta description? If so, install the WordPress SEO plugin to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found to do this is to install the [Yoast SEO plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/) which allows you to manage that right on all posts including the blog listing that you referenced.

It's a good plugin to have in general for SEO anyway so it's win-win.